libc.so react native memory leak crash on firebase crashlytics
I'm encountering persistent crashes in my React Native app (version 0.72.7) with Hermes enabled. I've analyzed the memory graph for a video component in my app, which has raised concerns about potential memory leaks. I'm seeking guidance on the following:
What is considered ideal or normal memory consumption for a React Native app?
Could the memory usage I'm observing be causing these crashes, possibly due to memory leaks?
Are there recommended tools or strategies for diagnosing and resolving memory-related issues in React Native apps?
I'd appreciate insights from the community on how to approach these performance issues and optimize my app's memory management. If additional information is needed, such as specific crash logs or detailed memory usage data, please let me know, and I'll provide them promptly.[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/tClTnS8y.png)
I tried enabling hermes upgrading rn version to 74 removing any unwanted listeners in the component that was causing this much amount of memory leak
